# AWT GUI - the same app show vast different frame sizes on different PC screen sizes

Tags: java, user-interface, awt, layout-manager

I wrote a Java AWT GUI App which looks great on my 24" monitor. When I port the APP to a 14" laptop the Java frames look way too small. Obviously, something has to change, but what? A snippet of the frame definition follows:

```
   Private void initialize() {      
    this.setSize(700,400);                       // <-- Frame size 
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setTitle("GPDisplay");
    this.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
```

I think that they key is the "Layout", but I am unfamiliar with how to use it. Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Too much code, in my opinion. It takes a lot of lines to come out with the finished screen.

Comment: *"Too much code, in my opinion."* Whatever. Note that there are two separate close reasons that mention 'no MCVE' as part of the reason. I chose one of them. All the best with it, there are people with MCVEs to help.

Comment: I was hoping for a built-in facility that would compensate for the pixel issue. Sending all of the affected code into this forum, and with out that, is pointless.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve the problem by automatically getting the screen size first, and then the control position is associated with the get screen value.

Comment: I have been working on that angle. The 12" screen has more (and smaller) pixels than the 24". I can get the values you mention but the amount of code to enact it everywhere I need is enormous.